# where does this URL need urlencoding?

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, file-get-contents, urlencode

I hosted a website i worked on on amazon web services, and for some reason some things dont work compared to when I run it locally on localhost.

of those things are the

```
if (array_key_exists("error", $json))
```

function and

the `file_get_contents` function.

Ive commented out the array key exists part and that solved the issue, at least for that part of logging in, until i get to the view documents page where a slim application error displays

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

and the issue for that lies in the viewdocspage.php file, particularly this code:

```
<?php
                 $raw = file_get_contents("http://cosoft.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/cosoft/mywiki/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&format=json");
                 $pages_response = json_decode($raw, true);
                 $pages_array = $pages_response["query"]["allpages"];
                 $page_titles = [];
```

I looked and read up on many threads that the issue lies with the file_get_contents in which the URL contains special characters, such as spaces (which mine doesnt have) and so needs to be encoded, using urlencode (or rawurlencode..?)

now ive tried encoding the whole url like this:

```
$raw = file_get_contents(urlencode("http://cosoft.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/cosoft/mywiki/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&format=json"));
```

but that resulted in this error:
[slim error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6oKH.png)

> Message: file_get_contents(http%3A%2F%2Fcosoft.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com%2Fcosoft%2Fmywiki%2Fapi.php%3Faction%3Dquery%26list%3Dallpages%26format%3Djson): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

---

I figured that this may happen since I read that not all the URL should be wrapped by this encoding, but heres where Im stuck: which part of the url do i use the encoding on? the only special characters i keep coming accross regarding this error is spaces, but i dont have any spaces, so its something else which i dont know what it is...

Help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: great. even with a detailed as much as possible organized and unique question i get a downvote with no explanation. smh

Comment: wow...2 more downvotes. can someone explain?

Comment: I suspect the downvotes may be because you heard the sound of hoofbeats and you are searching for a zebra while overlooking the horse that is staring at you: `http://cosoft.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/cosoft/mywiki/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&format=json` does, in fact, return 404 Not Found.  You have an invalid URL, or you're getting IP restricted, or you're not sending credentials... but this is not a urlencoding problem.  There's nothing in the URL requiring encoding (which is generally used on `?the_keys=and_values_in&ur=query_string`, but not on the ? = & that delimit them).

Comment: Ok well those down voters could have made my life and others lives easier but simply telling me this straight up that it doesn't need url encoding and it's something else. I clearly stated that it's working on localhost, and I also clearly justified my position in truly seeking an answer by searching and understanding many threads on the Web for hours. This forum is supposed to be a help for everyone, so why do those down voters think everyone should be at the sane level of experience and knowledge as them? So wats the point of stack exchange forums? Why does Dani web treat us friendlier?

Answer (score 1):

You would just need to url_encode the parameters. Say you had a value `$value='My name is earl'`
If you wanted to pass this value as a parameter in your url
`http://somesite.com/?name=$value` there would be spaces in the value that is url_encoded. So if you encode it as `'http://somesite.com/?name='.urlencode($value)`, when this is encoded the value will turn into `My+name+is+earl`

Comment: so in that URL i have, what are the parameters and where should url encoding be done? because i know how to use it for spaces, but i dont have spaces in mine, so i dont know which special characters need it in my problem

Comment: You are using a hard-coded URL with no special characters that would need encoding. Leave your url as-is without url_encode. The reason you are getting that 404 error is because the page does not exist. I just visited it in my browser and got a 404 error

Comment: @masterofcatastrophe: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: thats because i used urlencode around the whole thing. without the encode i would still get a similar error, failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
so searching online people had solutions with urlencode, but i dont know where to use it

Answer (score -1):

Reading resources from a URL may be restricted by the server's configuration.
http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

You should use CURL for this.

Comment: i also seen CURL being a proposed solution, but it looked complicated to simply using urlencode. I wouldnt really know how to implement CURL here, also fopen is already enabled because running it on the localhost server is working fine, its just AWS that it giving the problem

Comment: That isn't the problem here.  The error would be completely different, and if you read the code you can see that they've obviously mangled the URL, which is why it doesn't exist.

Comment: CURL could be used even to manage the parameters properly.
Also url fopen is commonly disabled so he would have problems with this at some point